# which technology i need to use to build a customizable (also cross platform) mobile app?

Tags: .net, mobile, jquery-mobile, dojo, phonegap-plugins

Customiation is the main priority of this application.

- We have an existing mobile app based on DoJo, Is it a good idea to use this as a base for our new app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your question isn't a straight forward one. There are 2 approaches here;

DoJo(Cordova) - If you decide to build your mobile app based on DoJo(Cordova) you will have an hybrid app which will not perform as good as a native application. The good side is you can get a mobile app quickly with few extra work. A major disadvantage is in the future you may need core native features which are not available in the cordova library and this will probably mean you need to write your app all over again natively and performance may now be a major factor which cordova sucks at.

React Native - This will help you build a native mobile app with the same knowledge of javascript you know. The good thing about this approach is that you can decide to write Java/swift for certain native functionalities which makes the possibilities limitless. The only issue is you would have to start the mobile app from scratch unlike with the above approach therefore taking longer to finish.

I'll advice you go with the React Native approach.